# TFS 2012 Alert when test case fails

Tags: tfs-workitem, tfs-alerts

When using TFS 2012 we create Product Backlog Items (PBI) and assign those to a responsible developer.  We generate a test suite per PBI.  We'd like to alert the "owner" of the PBI (whoever the PBI is assigned to) when a test case fails that is on a suite associated with the PBI.

Does TFS 2012 support this kind of alert?

(Note: I'm using the Scrum 2.2 process template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not appear this is possible through the standard TFS alerts setup.  The main issue is that the status of the test case (active, passed, failed) is actually associated with a test run and not the test case itself.  The test run does not appear to be a work item I can query against.

I believe we will go with creating a bug when a Test Case fails (easy enough to trigger emails regarding new bugs)...I think this maybe the more "traditional" approach in the Scrum template.